# What the meaning of "leaving behind a bread-crumb trail of reports like this one :"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, expressions

I don't grasp the expression bread-crumb in this phrase : "physicians would discover slowly, leaving behind a bread-crumb trail of reports like this one :....".

Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bread crumbs" are a metaphor for leaving a trail behind. Sometimes this is deliberate, such as to mark where you've been when exploring. Sometimes it's accidental, such as when a thief leaves clues like footprints at the scene of the crime, which detectives can "follow" later to find the thief.

The metaphor may have originated with the German fairy tale [Hansel and Gretel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel) in which the characters leave behind bread crumbs so that they can find their way in the woods.

In modern language, "bread crumbs" also refer to a common style of navigation links on a web page or in a computer program, where the links are broken out hierarchically to show the user where they are in the structure of the program like a trail of bread crumbs through the woods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enlightenment! It's very king of you, for the poor French I am.

Comment: @Jérôme Je vous en prie!